# How do i display a users name and avatar on my website when using discord Oauth2?

Tags: javascript, html, discord, discord.js

I'm new to this so can you help.
I'm make a discord bot list.
Here website
https://technologicalflawedglueware.animeloveruwu.repl.co

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that hard. Just do the following:

- Get the code from the redirect URL,
- make an access token exchange,
- get your access token response,
- make an API call to get your information.

Here you can the official [documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2).

Comment: im using html 
how do i code that

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. There is no way to code this in HTML. HTML isn't a programming language. This topic is a little bit big. If you want help let me know your discord name and tag.

Comment: her my discord tag Rika Takanashi#5066